# Link to corresponding path in other locale (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

I have a multi-lingual application in Ruby on Rails 4. For that I use the following  domains:

- Swedish: exempel.se
- English: example.com
- French:  fr.example.com
- Spanish: es.example.com

I want to be able to link to the corresponding path in another corresponding locale. For example if I am at www.exempel.se/denna-bloggpost I want to be able to easily link to (English/Spanish/French) to e.g. www.example.com/this-here-blog-post and es.example.com/este-posto-de-bloggo (sorry, can't speak Spanish :)).

I understand this is done with `link_to 'Spanish', locale => :es` but this gives me the url `www.exempel.se/denna-bloggpost?locale=es` which is not what I want. I expect to access `es.example.com/esto-posto-de-bloggo`

It seems like `default_url_options` has something to do with this but I can't make it work.

How do I solve this?

Edit (2017-03-30): I will also need this solution for hreflang in the  section.

I am using the `route_translator` gem.

I have seen several solutions for this but they all include solutions with `?locale=en` or are just to simplified (like, only working for one single controller). What I am hoping for is a solution that would do something like this:

```
<% I18n.available_locales.each |locale| do %>
 <% I18n.t(this route e.g. /denna-bloggpost) #=> /este-posto-de-bloggo, /this-blog-post, /le-post-du-blog %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Would you consider a solution where the link is to `www.exempel.se/denna-bloggpost?locale=es`, but upon clicking this it redirects you to `es.exempel.com/denna-bloggpost`?

Comment: I really would prefer not (thought about that as well) since it would likely confuse Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the locale-specific routes that `route_translator` generates for you. Run `rake routes` to see what these are. And then:

```
# Create links for every other locale
<% (I18n.available_locales - I18n.locale).each |locale| do %>
  # Example URL helper here - replace with your own!
  <%= Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.send("posts_#{locale}_url",
 'denna-bloggpost') %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, this probably works fine, but this is still not a generic solution since it requires "posts_". Thus, I need to define this for every different view and cannot have it in the application.html.erb.

Comment: @Christoffer: for a more generic solution, you can replace `"posts"` with `controller_name` e.g. `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.send("#{controller_name}_#{locale}_url", params['slug'])`

Comment: Ah, perfect! That will do it then!

Answer (score 1):

In order to create such a dynamic mapping, you must presumably have something like this defined in your application config:

```
APP_CONFIG = {
  # ...
  base_urls: {
    se: 'exempel.se',
    en: 'example.com',
    fr: 'fr.example.com',
    es: 'es.example.com'
  }
  # ...
}
```

(It wouldn't necessarily need to be in this format, of course; this is just an example.)

In the locale switching menu, you can then define your links like this:

```
link_to("French", "#{APP_CONFIG[:base_urls][:fr]}#{request.env['PATH_INFO']}")
```

---

In order to actually **set** the locale in your application, you could then place something like this in your `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_action :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = APP_CONFIG[:base_urls].key(request.host) || I18n.default_locale
  end
end
```

For more information, see here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#managing-the-locale-across-requests

Comment: Thanks for the help but your solution does not work due to the fact that request.env['PATH_INFO'] collects the current path like (/denna-bloggpost) and adds it to the base_url to create "es.example.com/denna-bloggpost" instead of es.example.com/este-posto-de-bloggo. I thought there would be a more 'elegant' solution to this using :locale => :es but just tell Rails to, instead of using ?locale=es use my default url-system. Is there no solution like that?

Comment: Ah right sorry, I forgot that point. So you all need to do is create some function that maps the current route (possibly with the current locale), to the corresponding route for a different locale? E.g. `translate_route("denna-bloggpost", :en, :fr) == "este-posto-de-bloggo"`? What seems like a very application-specific problem, so I'd need to know more about how your routing model currently works -- but I don't imagine creating such a method would be too hard?

Comment: Also, a quick google search found me [this](https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator), which may potentially help...

Comment: Thanks again Tom. It seems, however, that this solution is just leading further away from a "real" answer. I am just assuming then that this can be solved more out of the box. I am running translated routes already etc but my real issue is that the link_to with locale does not map up with that translated route.

Answer (score 0):

This question is addressed a number of times and many ways.  Yet the simplest approach in my opinion is

```
<%= link_to "ру", request.params.merge( locale: 'ru' ) %>
```